# Iterate over an array of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had to resort to this bodge to set height of div01-05 different to div11-15 :(

```
var maxheight = divheight;
var dayofweek = <?echo date("w",strtotime($today));?>;
var heightoffset = (2 - dayofweek) * 40;

var days = jQuery('div.day01, div.day02, div.day03, div.day04, div.day05');
for (i=0; i<days.length; i++){
    var hh = jQuery(days[i]).prop("scrollHeight");
    if (hh > maxheight) {
        maxheight = hh;
    };
    jQuery(days[i]).height(divheight+heightoffset);
};

var days = jQuery('div.day11, div.day12, div.day13, div.day14, div.day15');
for (i=0; i<days.length; i++){
    var hh = jQuery(days[i]).prop("scrollHeight");
    if (hh > maxheight) {
        maxheight = hh;
    };
    jQuery(days[i]).height(divheight-heightoffset);
};

//Back to full array for further processing
var days = jQuery('div.day01, div.day02, div.day03, div.day04, div.day05, div.day11, div.day12, div.day13, div.day14, div.day15');
```

Would someone please put me out of my misery and show me how to just iterate over all the divs and do a conditional set height.

One caveat is that PHP is greating the divs and div.day01 -04 might not exists depending on day of the week div.day05 always does and so do divs day11-15

regards
Simon

Final code result(having corrected to using ids instead of classes :)

```
    jQuery('div[id^="day"]').each(function() { 
        var hh = jQuery(this).prop("scrollHeight");
        if (hh > maxheight) {maxheight = hh;};
        var cn = jQuery(this).attr('id').split(" ")[0]; // Since PHP is creating these classes, we can safely assume "day" will always be the first.
        var num = parseInt(cn.slice(-2),10); // extract the last two characters and convert to an integer
        if (num >=1 && num <= 5) {
            jQuery(this).height(divheight+heightoffset);
        }else if(num >=10 && num <= 15){
            jQuery(this).height(divheight-heightoffset);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div[class^="day"]').each(function() { 
  var cn = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0]; // Since PHP is creating these classes, we can safely assume "day" will always be the first.
  var num = parseInt(cn.slice(-2),10); // extract the last two characters and convert to an integer
  if (num >=1 && num <= 5) {
    // Working with div 01-05
  }else if(num >=10 && num <= 15){
    // Working with div 11-15
  }
});
```

Comment: The `div`s may contain other classes, so you should probably check to see if the div contains the class `/day\d*/` first.

Comment: That's why I said IDs should be used instead. :-)

Comment: re your $div each function - how do I change this to just iterate over the divs 01-15 as I have other divs as well and thanks for the heads up over the class/id mistook - I'd obviuosly got away with it so far but will correct :)

Comment: @SimpleSi -- changed the code so it should match only those classes. That said, you REALLY ought to set the ID of each div to day01,...day15 (and replace `class` with `id` everywhere in my answer) instead of using classes. If a div has more than one class, my code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over all divs on the page, use

```
jQuery('div').each(function(d) {
    //This code will run for each div on the page
    //Just put any conditionals in here
    //Use jQuery(this) to refer to the current div
});
```

**EDIT:**

Use `jQuery(this).attr('name')` to access the name of the current element.

Use `jQuery(this).attr('id')` to access the id of the current element.

Use `jQuery(this).hasClass('classname')` (boolean) to check if the current element has the indicated class.

Comment: Sorry - there are other divs so code must only apply to days01..days15 and I don't know how to access the name of the div being processed to do the conditional test - thats my problem :(

Comment: @SimpleSi That is described in my answer. I'm appending more detail to it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('div')` to loop through every `div` on the page, then use a regex to get just the `div`s you want.  You can even limit the `div`s jQuery loops over using `[class*="day"]`.

```
$('div[class*="day"]').each(function(){
   var dayClass = this.className.match(/day\d*/);
   if(dayClass != null){ // if the div contains the class day..
     var dayID = dayClass[0].replace('day', ''); // 01, 02, 03, etc.
     if(dayID >=1 && dayID <= 5){
     }
     else if(dayID >= 11 && dayID <= 15){
     }
     else{
     }
   }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9kxSF/1/

A better idea here would be to give all the `div`s a class of say "dayDiv", as well was the "day01" or "day02" class, so then you could do `$('div.dayDiv')` to get the `div`s you wanted.

```
<div class="dayDiv day01"></div>
<div class="dayDiv day02"></div>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$('div.dayDiv').each(function(){
    var dayClass = this.className.match(/day\d*/);
    var dayID = dayClass[0].replace('day', ''); // 01, 02, 03, etc.
    if(dayID >=1 && dayID <= 5){
    }
    else if(dayID >= 11 && dayID <= 15){
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I didn't realise you could give divs more than one "name"

Comment: @SimpleSi: You can give elements multiple classes, but not names or IDs.